# Is my proof for $\mu_{*} (A) \le \mu^{*} (A)$ correct?

Tags: measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

We have $(X, \mathcal{A}, \mu_0)$

Let $\mu_0$ be a finite function on an algebra $\mathcal{A}$, such that $\mu_0 : \: \mathcal{A} \rightarrow \mathbb{K}$, where $\forall_{A \in \mathcal{A}} \: |\mu_0 (A)| < \infty$

$\mu_0$ fulfills the follwing conditions:

1. $\mu_0 (\varnothing) = 0$
2. $\mu_0 (\bigcup_{j=1}^{\infty} A_j) = \sum_{j=1}^{\infty} \mu_0 (A_j)$, where $\left\{ A_j \right\}_{j=1}^{\infty}$ is a family of pairwise disjoint sets from $\mathcal{A}$, such that $\bigcup_{j=1}^{\infty} A_j \in \mathcal{A}$

We define the measure $$\mu^* (A) := \inf \left\{ \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \mu_0 (A_n) \: : \: A_n \in \mathcal{E} , \: A \subset \bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty} A_n\right\}$$ where $\mathcal{E}$ is a family of sets, such, that:

1. $\varnothing \in \mathcal{E}$
2. $A, B \in \mathcal{E} \: \Rightarrow \: A \cap B \in \mathcal{E}$
3. $A \in \mathcal{E} \: \Rightarrow \: A^C$ is a finite sum of disjoint elements from $\mathcal{E}$ ($A^C$ is the complement of $A$)

We also define: $$\mu_* (A) := \mu_0 (X) - \mu^* (X \backslash A)$$

We want to prove, that:

1. $\mu_* (A) \le \mu^* (A)$ for $A \in 2^X$
2. $\mu_* (A) = \mu^* (A)$ if $A$ is $\mu^*$-measurable

---

**Proof**

*ad 1.*

The Caratheodory Criterion for $\mu^*$ when $A \in 2^X$ is as follows: $$\mu^* (X) \le \mu^* (X \cap A) + \mu^* (X \backslash A)$$

If we suppose, that $X = \bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty} X_n$, then we'd have $$\mu^* (X) := \inf \left\{ \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \mu_0 (X_n) \: : \: X_n \in \mathcal{E} , \: X \subset \bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty} X_n = X \right\}$$

Because of $X \subset \bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty} X_n = X$ , we'd have, that $$\mu_0 (X) = \mu^* (X)$$

Coming back to our Caratheodory Condition, we'll have: $$\mu_0 (X) = \mu^* (X) \le \mu^* (X \cap A) + \mu^* (X \backslash A)$$

Now, using $\mu_* (A) := \mu_0 (A) - \mu^* (X \backslash A)$, we eventually get: $$\mu_* (A) := \mu_0 (X) - \mu^* (X \backslash A) = \mu^* (X) - \mu^* (X \backslash A) \le  \mu^* (X \cap A) + \mu^* (X \backslash A) - \mu^* (X \backslash A) = \mu^* (X \cap A) = \mu^* (A)$$

*ad 2.*

This is analogically, because if we suppose that $A$ is $\mu^*$-measurable, then the Caratheodory condition will be $$\mu^* (X) = \mu^* (X \cap A) + \mu^* (X \backslash A)$$. So it's the same as above, the only difference being that instead of $\le$ we'd have $=$

---

Is my proof correct and complete? Are there some unanswered questions? Are there some comments to be made about certain aspects of my proof?

I'm not too sure about the $\mu_0 (X) = \mu^* (X)$ part, that's why I'm asking

Comment: In your definition of $\mu^*$, do you mean $A \in \mathcal{A}$ instead of $A \in \mathcal{E}$?

Comment: No, I mean $A \in \mathcal{E}$ (this is at least what's written in this exercise, maybe that's a mistake and it should be $\mathcal{A}$)